# Matlab: Toolbar buttons interfering with value returning? (GUIDE GUI)

Tags: matlab, user-interface, callback

So, recently I found a strange behaviour of Matlab GUIDE GUI toolbar buttons.

I have the "Toolbar" figure property set to 'auto' and a simple toolbar with three default buttons: drag, zoom-, zoom+.

Everything worked perfectly fine, until I decided to integrate this figure into a larger application in a sense that I needed to return value from this figure.

I therefore added uiwait() to the OpeningFcn, uiresume to CloseRequestFcn and value returning to OutputFcn.

After that modifications, any behaviour of the toolbar buttons disappeared. I mean, they still can be toggled and untoggled, but it basically does nothing.

How come? I need some way to have both the toolbar buttons and have a meaningful return value from the figure. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Could you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? That would boost your chances of someone solving your problem.

Comment: >>Could you provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example ?
With a binary GUI? Sure. Where do I upload the files?